# Coffeescript 'error: Invalid object key'

Tags: coffeescript

I'm very new to coffeescript. So what does this error actually mean?

this is the class

```
class Animation
    constructor: (t) ->
        @startTime: t
```

I'm trying to set it up so that this class has a member startTime initialized to t during construction. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is creating an object in the constructor (and not saving the reference anywhere) with a key of `@startTime`. The error occurs because `@` isn't a valid character for an object key.

Try this instead:

```
class Animation
    constructor: (@startTime) ->
```

Here's the generated JavaScript:

```
var Animation;

Animation = (function() {
  function Animation(startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
  }

  return Animation;

})();
```

---

Here's where you can see the syntax for what you wanted to do: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Here's the syntax you were incorrectly and unintentionally using: http://coffeescript.org/#literals (the section titled "Objects and Arrays")

Comment: I thought the @ symbol created a member, while just initializing a key made a local variable to that function. How would I go about making a local variable during the constructor?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: `@startTime = t` would create a member, things of the form `k: v` are just `{ k: v }` in disguise so `@startTime: t` is an attempt to write `{ @startTime: t }` which is a syntax error.

Comment: ah, interesting. That makes a lot more sense, thanks!